# C# | WebPermission-Exception on XP-machine

Tags: c#, networking, permissions, windows-xp

I'm writing a small C#-client which checks a homepage on a local server every 5 seconds. On a Windows-7-VM it works, but if I try running the client on a XP-virtual-machine I'm getting a `System.Net.WebPermission`-Exception. Both VMs have the same network settings (WinXP-IP=`10.0.1.100`, Win7-IP=`10.0.1.101`) and their network-adapters are set to bridged networking (in the Win7-VM the client works)

My code:

```
private string GetPageContent(string url)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string output = client.DownloadString(url);
    client.Dispose();
    return output;
}
```

The URL the WebClient tries to download looks like 
`http://10.0.1.25/info.php`

Is this a Windows XP specific problem or do I have to add some permissions?

Comment: What's the full exception?

Comment: `Unhandled Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at Client.Updater.GetPageContent(String url) `

That's the exception. I'm running the `WebClient.DownloadString` in a separate Thread, because there'll some other stuff later.